# В чем ошибка? Задача "строки наоборот"

Tags: python

Задача: В файле записано несколько строк текста (не более 100). Каждая строка содержит не более 100 символов (не считая символов окончания строки). Требуется написать программу, выводящую те же строки в том же порядке, только каждая строка «перевёрнута» - т.е. её символы записаны в обратном порядке.

Формат ввода
Во входном файле записано несколько строк (не более 100), каждая длиной не более 100 символов. В строках встречаются только следующие символы: заглавные и строчные буквы латинского алфавита, цифры, знаки препинания: точка (.) и запятая (,).

Формат вывода
В выходной файл требуется вывести «перевёрнутые» строки в исходном порядке.

Мое решение:

```
S=input()
while len(S)!=0:
   S=input()
   print(S[ : : -1])
```

Comment: что именно не так в вашем коде?

Answer (score 2):

Внимательно прочитайте задание. Там есть табличка, где указанно как вводятся данные, а именно **input.txt**. Поэтому нужно работать с файлом.

```
f = open('input.txt')
text = f.read().split('\n')
for s in text:
    print(s[::-1])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас то, что вводится в первом `input` просто пропадает - этот ввод участвует в проверке, но не в выводе. Лучше как-то так сделать:

```
while True:
   s = input()
   if not s:
       break
   print(s[::-1])
```

Comment: к сожалению, выдает ошибку во время исполнения(

Comment: @НорикСаргсян Странно. Возможно, вы успели скопировать код между правками, когда часть переменных `s` уже была маленькими, а часть оставались большими `S` )

Comment: вот я тоже не понимаю, почему ошибка возникает, хотя я последнее откорректированное вставил в компилятор на сайте..

Comment: @Danis я то ссылку дам, но это сайт Яндекс. контест. там нужно входить под своим логином. я уже кучу вариантов решения отправил и во всех он находит ошибку, хотя в wing все работает

Comment: @Danis я понял почему ошибка. там стоит ограничение по времени: 2 секунды

Comment: @НорикСаргсян Ну так там наверное не через input ввод, а как-то по-другому делается. Ваша программа висит на строке с input и выходит таймаут в итоге.

Comment: В условии четко сказано "Во входном файле..."  Т.е.  функция должна получать файл на входе, а автор вопроса пытается получить данные через input